# Extracting all values from an array of names tuples in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

This code strikes me as being a bit verbose. Is there a better way of extracting all the names parameters from an array of named tuples?

Here is a toy example. We have extracted `allPlayers` and `allScores`, from a Swift array of type `[(player : String, score : Int)]`.

```
var info : [(player : String, score : Int)] = Array()
let value1 = (player: "A", score: 1)
let value2 = (player: "B", score: 2)
let value3 = (player: "C", score: 3)
info.append(value1)
info.append(value2)
info.append(value3)

var allPlayers : [String] = Array()
var allScores : [Int] = Array()
for (player, score) in info {
    allPlayers.append(player)
    allScores.append(score)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map function to do that:

```
var names = info.map {
  $0.player
}
// names = ["A", "B", "C"]
```